# Modify class var in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, avl-tree

I'm currently working in my own AVL implementation, but I can get the rotate function to work correctly, because I can't modify the tree element passed by reference. Here it's my node class:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        self.left = None
        self.rigt = None
        self.parent = None
        self.height = 0

    def getLabel(self):
        return self.label

    def setLabel(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def getLeft(self):
        return self.left

    def setLeft(self, left):
        self.left = left
        self.left.setParent(self)
        self.left.setHeight(self.height + 1)

    def getRight(self):
        return self.rigt

    def setRight(self, right):
        self.rigt = right
        self.rigt.setParent(self)
        self.rigt.setHeight(self.height + 1)

    def getParent(self):
        return self.parent

    def setParent(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.height = (self.parent.getHeight() + 1 if
                        (self.parent is not None) else 0)

    def setHeight(self, height):
        self.height = height

    def getHeight(self):
        return self.height
```

After each insert, the function rebalance is called and the rotate function if it's necesary. The rotate function it's called as `self.rotate(n)` where n is the unbalanced node and the function rotate is

```
def rotate_right(self, node):
    n = Node(node.getLabel())
    n.setRight(node.getRight())
    n.setLeft(Node(node.getParent))
    node.setParent(n)
```

But when I try to print the tree after a rotation, it's stay the same state, looks like rotation doesn't work but a quick print in the rotate method show it works correctly.

Comment: For the love of Guido, *don't use getters and setters*. You have like 7 totally useless methods...

Comment: Please post the driver program to exhibit the problem.

Comment: And for the love of God, spell `right` - `right`, not `rigt`. :)

Comment: What should I use @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Normal attribute access: `node.right` instead of `node.getRight()`. Read [this](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php). Python is not Java/C++. It has properties and the descriptor protocol. Only implement those when you *need them*

Comment: what is it the driver program? @Prune

Comment: @rafaelleru: The driver program is the one that runs the test case.  The code you posted doesn't produce any output: it merely defines a class and exits.  A driver would create a tree, invoke `rotate`, and print out results to exhibit the problem.  See [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)